# Split feature by polygon and do multipart to singlepart in QGIS

Tags: qgis, multipart, singlepart

I am searching for a tool or a combination of tools in QGis to get done some line-cuttings. They have to follow some rules:

1. Lines should be cut at the borders of a raster. For example, the purple line in **picture 1** should be cut into 4 pieces as can be seen in **picture 2** (rasters 5-8).
2. Lines that leave a raster and enter the same raster afterwards should be cut into 2 separate lines (e.g. the red line in raster 1).
3. Lines that leave a raster and enter the same raster afterwards AND cross themselves inside this raster should not be cut by the line itself (e.g. the yellow line in raster 3) but only by the raster-borders.

**picture 1 - start**
[image: picture 1]

**picture 2 - what I try to get**
[image: picture 2]

So here's what I got so far:

I managed to cut lines (**picture 1**) by raster-borders to get line-pieces for each raster. Therefor I used the intersection-tool. The result is shown in **picture 3**. Using then "multipart features to single parts" the red line in raster 1 is cut into 3 pieces and the yellow line in raster 3 is cut into 6 pieces as shown in **picture 4**.

If you have a look at **picture 2** again, the red line in raster 1 should only be cut into 2 pieces and the yellow line in raster 3 should be cut into 3 pieces.

**picture 3**

[image: picture 3]

**picture 4 - what I got**

[image: picture 4]

Comment: Please have a look at `explode lines` in the toolbox. It should do exactly what you're looking for in step 3.

Comment: Thanks @Erik. Explode lines is not the right tool. Using it the line is seperated into multiple pieces. What I try to get are continous lines from raster border to raster border (picture 2).

Comment: Yeah, now your question is better structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

The SAGA tool line-polygon intersection does the job: `Menu Vector / Processing / Line-polygon intersection`, see result:

[image]

Compare with the original line and the settings I used:

[image]

### Specific problem - and how to overcome it

Using the data you provided, there is however a problem. In several cases, e.g. in grid cell no. 7, no line is created at all. Inspecting the data, the reason is because the line that crosses grid 7 has no vertex inside of 7 - all vertices lie outside, in grid cell no. 5 (extremely close to the border with 7) and in cell no. 8.

For this reason, you can use `Menu Vector / Processing / Densify by interval` to generat a new line with more vertices. Just define the interval in such a way that for sure every part of your line that finally should become a separate feature contains at least one vertex. With this line, now you can use Line-polygon intersection as describe.

[image]

In a first (failed) attempt to find a solution, I created points with `Menu Vector / Processing / Line intersections` to get the intersection points - maybe that could lead to another way to find a solution.

[image]

Comment: OK, so what is left to be resolved?

Comment: This gets me really close to what I need! By using `line-polygon-intersection` I got the right pieces of lines. Now there pops up another Problem. After running the tool some pieces are missing completely. In my case the line going through raster n.7. In the previous and the following raster the line appears.

Comment: Strange - is there something wrong with raster nr. 7 (e.g. no unique id)?

Comment: Why do you think the line in raster no. 7 is missing? Is it just a visualization problem? I had this too when creating my output and setting random colors: one line was in a very light yellow, barely visible. Or did you otherwise datermine that there is really a line missing?

Comment: I used `create grid` (extend input -> line-layer) which automatically creates a unique id for each feature. I can't select any line in raster nr. 7 because there is no - really strange. Changing symbology doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Can you somehow share the data to see if I can replicate the problem? Without that, it's difficult to guess.

Comment: You did not accidentaly checked the box `Selected features only` for the polygons in the dialog?

Comment: Be sure to have selected the option `[1]keep original line attributes` in the `Line intersections` dialog window - if I use the default setting `[0]one multiple line per polygon`, I also get just some of the lines

Comment: Sharing data if you upload it somewhere (cloud) and than post the link in the comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117159/discussion-between-leo-and-babel).

Comment: For the missing pieces like in cell no. 7 see now the updated solution